# Ошибка при сборке проекта webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Имеется проект со структурой

```
/src
    index.jsx
/.babelrc
/package.json
/webpack.js
```

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, World</h1>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            {
                "loose": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

webpack.js:

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    mode:  process.env.mode,
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.jsx'],

    output: {
        path:     path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: './bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:    /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:     {
                    loader:  'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    },
};
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "test-search",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "run:dev": "webpack-cli serve",
        "build:dev": "webpack"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "webpack": "^5.11.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
    }
}
```

При попытке запустить проект командой `webpack-cli serve` или `webpack` в консоль падает ошибка:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'search-test'

```
resolve './src' in 'search-test'
  using description file: \package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: \package.json (relative path: ./src)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        \src is not a file
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        \src.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        \src.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        \src.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        existing directory \src
          using description file: \package.json (relative path: ./src)
            using path: D:\projects\search-test\src\index
              using description file: \package.json (relative path: ./src/index)
                no extension
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                  \src\index doesn't exist
                .js
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                  \src\index.js doesn't exist
                .json
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                  \src\index.json doesn't exist
                .wasm
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                  \src\index.wasm doesn't exist
```

Как исправить данную ошибку или в какую сторону стоит копать?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в названии файла: вместо `webpack.js` должно быть `webpack.config.js`, либо можно указать конфиг принудительно при запуске скрипта через `--config ./webpack.js`